# Does Mie Scattering occur in Liquid or is Rayleigh scattering?

Tags: spectroscopy

Rayleigh scattering occurs when the dimensions of the scatter is much smaller than the wavelength of the incident electromagnetic radiation.

Mie scattering occurs when the dimensions of the scattered is much larger than the wavelength of the incident electromagnetic radiation. An example is when light is scattered by small water droplets in clouds.

So does Rayleigh or Mie scattering occur in liquid or bulk water?

It seems the answer is Mie scattering. But in Raman spectrometry. The incident light say 532nm is rayleigh backscattered in liquid. This is why the equipment needs to have notch filter, etc. So why does Rayleigh scattering (?) occur in liquid/bulk water when the particles are much larger than the wavelength of light? Or is it Mie Scattering that the raman device is filtering in the incident light backscattered?

Comment: I am not sure that Mie is the right model in a continuous homogeneous medium. Raman works at molecular basis or so. Mie needs interfaces. For theoretical treatment you can ask on Physics as well. A solution or a pure liquid in different from a suspension of solid or liquid in a gas is what I wanted to tell.  You are looking for abrupt change from a phenomenon to another where things can go smoother or coexist. See my other comment.

Answer (score 2):

> So does Rayleigh or Mie scattering occur in liquid or bulk water? So why does Rayleigh scattering (?) occur in liquid/bulk water when the particles are much larger than the wavelength of light?

What is the approximate size of water molecule? It is on the order of 2.7 Angstroms or 0.27 nanometers. When we are talking about visible light, the wavelength is 500 nm/0.27 times larger than the scatterer! In case of pure water and with visible light, Rayleigh scattering is observed along with Raman effect. If you disperse larger "particles" in water such as milk, one sees Mie scattering.

Comment: How about water droplets in cloud? It is still water molecules on order of 0.27 nanometers.  So why is it Mie scattered instead of Rayleigh scattered?

Comment: Those are either ice particles or large (compared to wavelength) droplets suspended in air.

Comment: "However, the water vapor will not readily condense without help from other particles. The air making up our atmosphere is full of microscopic floating particles of dust, soil, smoke, sea salts, and other matter. These particles are called condensation nuclei  when they assist in cloud formation. Just as water particles condense on grass to form dew, the tiny airborne particles of water vapor condense into liquid or ice on the surfaces of dust particles in the air. As more water vapor condenses into water droplets, a visible cloud forms." https://ssec.si.edu/stemvisions-blog/what-are-clouds

Comment: But cant water scattering be caused by ES scattering. In the Einstein—Smoluchowski theory, scattering is considered to be caused by the random motion of molecules which in a sufficiently small volume causes fluctuations of density and, therefore, of the dielectric constant.

Comment: I don't remember the specific details but keep in mind those are all classical theories. At that time quantum mechanics was developing. The classical version of scattering is that the incoming electric field oscillates the charge in the molecule at the same frequency. An oscillating charge then emits light of the same wavelength.

Comment: @Jtl also the phenomena can be concomitant. Certainly the Raman spectrum of the water droplet is the same and involves Rayleigh sc. What gives the Mie sc. would be the droplet of water at its interface rather than water molecules.

Comment: Guys. So the following statement is wrong? I read it from someone in the net (what is he talking about here?): "When the molecules aggregate the situation changes: scattered waves coming from different parts of the aggregate interfere and partially extinguish each other. For aggregate sizes larger than a wavelength, Mie scattering predominates. And in case of a homogeneous, nonabsorbing bulk liquid you treat the interaction with light in terms of reflection and refraction."?

Comment: To elaborate my comment above, others say the interaction in liquid water will not be as simple as photon / molecule scattering because each water molecule is bound to its neighbours much more than when it's in the gaseous phase. So they don't believe rayleigh scattering is even possible in bulk water, what do you say?

Comment: @M. Farooq Could it be that raman spectrometer can induce rayleigh scattering in water because of the way the laser is focused? Meaning for ordinary light or sunlight, the molecules aggregate and the situation changes where scattered waves coming from different parts of the aggregate interfere and partially extinguish each other?

Comment: @Jtl, No there is nothing like that. If you hold a glass of water in sunlight, it will also do Rayleigh scattering. Read Wikipedia on Rayleigh scattering.

Comment: @Jtl, Would you mind sharing what do you do with Raman spectrometers?

Comment: I own a raman spectrometer just to study intermolecular forces, to be familiar with them. For those with personal raman spectrometer in their bedroom. What do they do with it? just curious.

Comment: Just curious, whats is the make and model. One has to be really lucky in order to $own$ a Raman spectrometer in their bedroom :-)

Comment: I wanted to see Raman effect visually but unfortunately the lasers required to demonstrate this are too dangerous.

Comment: This is the model R532 http://enspectr.com/ my practical use is really analyzing sugar in wine. Please go to this site https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/light-propagation-in-water-is-the-scattering-rayleigh-scattering.956775/ the arguments of Jestocost are all wrong and the OP is right? pls. let me know so I can let them delete it if it's wrong or answers so vague it can confuse people. Thanks

Comment: All the discussion there is very vague and perhaps a mix of truth and junk.

Comment: If you wish to understand Raman effect, learn it from the horse's mouth. Read Raman's discovery paper. All of them are freely available.